# Reference problem with an SSIS project in Microsoft Visual Studio when launching a script task

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

My script below uses the reference \Newtonsoft.Json.dll which is at the root of my project.

When I start the script from the control flow, an error appears because my reference is not taken into account.

How can I integrate this reference so that it is also used when the script is launched from the control flow tab?

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
#endregion

namespace ST_0651a7db5fbe4732a5944a76a31f37a4
{

    public class Entry
    {
        public string API { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Auth { get; set; }
        public bool HTTPS { get; set; }
        public string Cors { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        
        public void Main()
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var json = "";
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.publicapis.org/entries");
            }

            Root root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

            foreach (Entry entry in root.Entries)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine("API: " + entry.API);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Description: " + entry.Description);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Auth: " + entry.Auth);
                //Debug.WriteLine("HTTPS: " + entry.HTTPS);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Cors: " + entry.Cors);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Link: " + entry.Link);
                //Debug.WriteLine("Category: " + entry.Category);
                //Debug.WriteLine("");

                string connectionString = @"Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=******;User ID=*******;Password=********;";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    // Open the connection
                    connection.Open();

                    // Create the insert statement
                    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO JSON_DATA(API, [Description], Auth, HTTPS, Cors, Link, Category) " +
                        "VALUES('" + entry.API.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + entry.Description.Replace("'", "''") + "', '" + entry.Auth + "', '" + entry.HTTPS + "', '" + entry.Cors + "', '" + entry.Link + "', '" + entry.Category + "')";

                    // Create a SqlCommand object with the insert statement and the SqlConnection object
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);

                    // Execute the insert statement
                    int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

However, if I create a C# project with the same code and run it directly, everything works fine.

Comment: Is it because the Newtonsoft.Json.dll assembly is not loaded correctly when executing the script from the control flow tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced assembly will have to be installed in the GAC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/referencing-other-assemblies-in-scripting-solutions?view=sql-server-ver16

PS If you plan to deploy and run your SSIS project on a server then you will also need to install the same assembly to the GAC on the target server

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve my problem thanks to your advice. 

For your information, there's good documentation here: https://www.onlinebuff.com/article_how-to-deploy-an-assembly-into-gacglobal-assembly-cache-_38.html